# XSLT popular usages

Tags: xml, xslt

Where are common usages for xslt.
I can't think of a time I have ever used them?

I have been  doing computing for quite a long time and never came across it's usage.  Is it one of those things that get buried in libraries?  Is it the case once they get built they never cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that XML allows definition of custom vocabularies, a natural need arises to transform between those vocabularies.  XSLT is wonderful for matching patterns from one XML document and then creating another XML document based on data from those patterns.  Oftentimes the input and output documents will be based on different vocabularies.  But not always.  Sometimes they'll be different parts or different versions of the same vocabulary.  Sometimes the output won't be XML at all but just text.  What's common is the need to map from an XML document to something else.  This need arises often, and   XSLT is great at it.

XSLT can appear foreign to newcomers because it is not an imperative language.  Rather than controlling a flow of statements to achieve a result, XSLT processing proceeds by matching patterns against an input XML document and outputting selective parts to an output XML document.  Selecting parts of the input XML document is done via XPath expressions, which are to XML as regular expressions are to text.  XPath is so effective that you'll find it available in library form in languages other than XSLT.

You'll find that the XSLT community, including many regulars here, to be very helpful.  Feel free to follow-up with specific questions if you do decide to pursue XSLT development, but be aware that accepted form here on Stack Overflow generally calls for more specific questions, preferably regarding specific code.  Overly broad or opinion-oriented questions don't do well here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I had not expected the question to last at all.  I have to talk to perspective client and part of the needs is XSLT - I wanted to be a little prepared.

Comment: @Soy XSLT is one of those things that is incredibly useful if you have to work with XML, especially when *producing new XML* (or other forms of output) from input XML is part of your task (its emphasis is XML *transformation*). However, it's an unusual language that many beginners have a hard time picking up, so often they substitute it by something they already know, like writing loops over a DOM document in their favorite imperative language. This works for simple cases, but more complex transformations can become amazingly elegant in XSLT and and a complete mess in imperative languages.

Comment: If you want a forum that appreciates wide-ranging questions like this, try the xsl-list at mulberrytech.com. Of course, everyone there is an XSLT enthusiast, so you won't get a balanced set of opinions!